# JS object accessing private variable as an object

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Given this object:

```
var OBJ = (function(){

    var dom = {
            prop1 : 'something',
            prop2 : 'something',
            prop3 : prop1
        }

    return dom.prop3;

})();
```

How would i go to achieve the prop3 reference (ideally without creating a method) ? i tried:

> this.prop1, dom.prop1, this.dom.prop1

Comment: Technically, you can't do this... You need to assign prop3 value after initializing dom object. `dom.prop3 = dom.prop1;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't access the properties of an object before you have finished creating it. Create the object, then assign additional values.

```
var dom = {
        prop1 : 'something',
        prop2 : 'something'
};
dom.prop3 = dom.prop1;
```